# How to assign an empty value to an object attribute in Django Admin Interface?

Tags: python, django, model

I'm designing an eBay-like website. My project has several models, one of which, namely "Listing", represents all existing products:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    image_url = models.URLField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="created_listings")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="won_listings", null=True)
```

I need the winner attribute to be able to equal an empty value. But when I try to assign it an empty value in Django Admin Interface, I get an error:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [**`blank=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#blank) to make the field non-required:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    # …
    winner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="won_listings",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).